# When I add value to SqlDataRecord number is rounding

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I add a value to my SqlDataRecord some how it is round the value.  I am not sure what is causing it.

**EDIT:** John made a good point Left out the property type for dm which is "decimal?"

```
TotalCount = 2.5245332200983

SqlDataRecord rec = new SqlDataRecord(
                new SqlMetaData("TotalCount", SqlDbType.Decimal));

rec.SetNullableDecimal(0,dm.TotalCount);

When it is written to the DB it is showing 3.0000000000000
```

Database Type added so I can pass a TVP:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TestCount AS TABLE(
TotalCounts decimal(38,20) NULL
);
```

Database Table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestCountTbl(
TotalCounts                 decimal(38,20) NULL);
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the SqlDbType wrong?

**EDIT:** Per @user957902 I had to add precision / scale to my SqlDataRecord....totally makes sense...duh.  So I added that and works like a charm.   Thanks All!

```
SqlDataRecord rec = new SqlDataRecord(
                new SqlMetaData("TotalCount", SqlDbType.Decimal,38,20));
```

Comment: What is dm? You are showing `TotalCount` on the top, but then later on it looks like a property/field on a variable called dm. What's that type?

Comment: Hi John the property type is decimal?

Comment: Everything we can see looks good... is there any more code you can show us? Maybe how you execute the query? The relevant stored procedure source?

Comment: I cannot find SetNullableDecimal in MSDN. There is SetDecimal, but no SetNullableDecimal: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqldatarecord.aspx

Comment: Sorry I added an extension method to handle when the element was empty I am under the covers using SetDecimal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation for the SqlMetaData constructor you are using [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127242.aspx), for SqlDbType.Decimal, the default for Precision is 18 and for scale  is **0**. So by default its not going to store anything past the decimal. You will need to use the constructor that allows you to set precision and scale descibed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127245.aspx).

```
public SqlMetaData(
    string name,
    SqlDbType dbType,
    byte precision,
    byte scale
)
```